# Why am I unable to see a folder in a ntfs formated drive

Tags: ntfs

I am running ubuntu 12.04. My problem: In a ntfs formatted disk I have created one folder and stored some files. Now it is showing nothing in that drive. But if I check the size of the disk there is still some space used. How can I get into that folder now. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the folder is not just hidden (i.e. it starts with a dot `.`)? Try opening the drive and then press Ctrl+H.

Comment: I tried it, and even checked on terminal by "ls -al" command. It is not showing that folder.

Comment: Please, could you paste the relevant line (or the whole output) you get from `mount`? I'm interested in seeing the mount flags, as ntfs-3g (the NTFS driver for Linux) has some options to hide special files. Also, if you remember the name of the "lost" directory, could you try to run `ls -ld "name of the dir"`? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, i did't get u, which command i have to use for mount flag information..??

Comment: No worries. To know the mount flags just run `mount` without arguments and paste the output on your question.

Comment: PFA, attached the result as image in problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

May be similar to reported bug [Data saved to a fuseblk (Windows NTFS) file system is silently lost](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/800921)